# How can I use an undefined symbol in a fn in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In clojure I would like to write a function which I can call like this:

```
(function undefined-symbol-which-means-something-else)
```

: Is there any way of writing such a function without resorting to ', :, or using a macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the symbol is undefined, this is always going to give you an error. This is because Clojure will try to resolve the symbol before calling the function, and fail.

Some options to consider (in my personal order of preference...):

- Use a keyword (i.e. ":my-keyword") - this is what they were designed for after all! You never need to pre-define keywords. Also this is probably the most idiomatic way of doing things.
- Use a regular string as a parameter. You can always convert this into a symbol later if you need to with (symbol "somename")
- If function is a macro rather than a function, then you could theoretically achieve something like what you want by reinterpreting the symbol on the fly. This works because macro expansion happens before evaluation.